# Electron White Flash on every Rendering process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm new to Electron JS Framework. Was reading plenty of that, want to know how to solve that one. It's obvious that on loading new html/page or something that redirects to new html file it calls rendering process on each html call. And that's causing that "White Flash" before the new page loads.

Just to be clear, would like to know how to load html files wihout that flash or maybe it's possible to wait on press till rendering process of that page is complete?

Would like to get some help here. Thanks!

Electron version : `"electron": "^1.7.9"`

Comment: You should provide some more information. For instance what electron version you're on and so on! 

By the way, are you meaning this issue: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4985 ? In that case it should be fixed in this https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/4995 .

Comment: Updated post @chrisv

Comment: I think it should be implemented in this version im using. am i right? But not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ready-to-show` event description from from the [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md)

> While loading the page, the ready-to-show event will be emitted when the renderer process has rendered the page for the first time if the window has not been shown yet. Showing the window after this event will have no visual flash

Simple example

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  win.show()
})
```

Comment: I know that is when i'm creating first BrowserWindow, but now i have created it, so i want to load new URL in same win.

Comment: And its not about window rendering, i want new html file to be loaded on click, i do it, when i click it it redirects to another html file but flashes before.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, could you please help me out. @Ervinas34